TypeError: unhashable type: 'ArrayObject'
When I run the following Python code, an error occurs. What should I do to get this code to run?
here is the code :
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def merge_pdfs(pdf_list, output_pdf):
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    
    for pdf in pdf_list:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)
        
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            pdf_writer.add_page(page)
            
    with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as out_pdf:
        pdf_writer.write(out_pdf)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_files = ['2019.pdf', '2020.pdf']
    merge_pdfs(pdf_files, 'merged_output.pdf')

here is the error message：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python\pdf_op.py", line 43, in <module>
    merge_pdfs(pdf_files, 'merged_output.pdf')
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python\pdf_op.py", line 11, in merge_pdfs
    pdf_writer.add_page(page)
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 321, in add_page
    return self._add_page(page, list.append, excluded_keys)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 271, in _add_page
    page = cast("PageObject", page_org.clone(self, False, excluded_keys))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 181, in clone
    d__._clone(self, pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 243, in _clone
    v.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 181, in clone
    d__._clone(self, pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 243, in _clone
    v.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_base.py", line 247, in clone
    obj = self.get_object()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_base.py", line 259, in get_object
    obj = self.pdf.get_object(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1260, in get_object
    retval = read_object(self.stream, self)  # type: ignore
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 1045, in read_object
    return DictionaryObject.read_from_stream(stream, pdf, forced_encoding)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic\_data_structures.py", line 395, in read_from_stream
    if not data.get(key):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ArrayObject'

python version 3.12.5,how can i run this code successfully, thanks in advance.

what version of pypdf are you using?

Thank you for your reply，the version of PyPDF2 is 3.0.1,is there anything wrong?

You need to downgrade to version 2.  There are breaking changes that are not well documented in version 3.  pip uninstall PyPDF2 then pip install PyPDF2==2.12.1

it works, however, the same issue occurred on line 15 pdf_writer.write(out_pdf), is it the Python version or pypdf version that is incorrect?

here is the error message: ![err]https://imgur.com/NcfRgQI

I recommend migrating from the unmaintained PyPDF2 to pypdf. If the issue persists, you probably want to provide the corresponding document and your code in an upstream issue.
